# Django view get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

I am making API with Django.

Crawled data is saved well in DB, but I have a problem with making API.

[image]

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import ReviewData
from .models import BuildingData
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import ReviewSerializer
from .serializers import BuildingSerializer
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

class BuildingInfoAPI(APIView):
    def get(request):
        queryset = BuildingData.objects.all()
        serializer = BuildingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
class ReviewListAPI(APIView):
    def get(request):
        queryset = ReviewData.objects.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from crawling_data.views import ReviewListAPI
from crawling_data.views import BuildingInfoAPI

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/buildingdata/', BuildingInfoAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/buildingdata/<slug:slug>/', ReviewListAPI.as_view())
]
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ReviewData
from .models import BuildingData

class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    class Meta :
        model = BuildingData        
        fields = '__all__'

class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    class Meta :
        model = ReviewData        
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

# Create your models here.
from django.utils.text import slugify

def generate_unique_slug(klass, field):
    origin_slug = slugify(field, allow_unicode=True)
    unique_slug = origin_slug
    numb = 1
    while klass.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        unique_slug = '%s-%d' % (origin_slug, numb)
        numb += 1
    return unique_slug

class BuildingData(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, allow_unicode=True, default=uuid.uuid1)
    building_loc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    building_call = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    building_time = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.slug:  # edit
            if slugify(self.building_name, allow_unicode=True) != self.slug:
                self.slug = generate_unique_slug(BuildingData, self.building_name)
            else:  # create
                self.slug = generate_unique_slug(BuildingData, self.building_name)
            super(BuildingData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

'''
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.building_name, allow_unicode=True)
        try:
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print(f"the repeated slug is: `{self.slug}`")
            raise 
'''
    
    

    

class ReviewData(models.Model):
    #building = models.ForeignKey(BuildingData, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    building_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    review_content = models.TextField()
    star_num = models.FloatField()
```

I think there's no problem with models.

But I can't find which makes get() error.

And I think error from(api/buildingdata/) prevents making slug url(api/buildingdata//) pages. (It says page not found when I enter slug url)

Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: You need to add the `self` parameter to your view methods: `def get(self, request, ...):`

Comment: Thanks! I think I can fix slug error

Answer (score 3):

add self parameter to your get method like this:`def get(self,request)` or just use [generic views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) more clear and DRY.